# FitNesse: Could not invoke constructor for SeleniumDriverSetup[0]

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, fitnesse

So, I've successfully completed the installation of IntelliJ using [hsac-fitnesse-fixtures installation guide](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/Installation-guide).

Next I've set up a project, added the [IntelliJ Idea Fitnesse plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7908-fitnesse), added a Maven configuration.

FitNesse runs correctly, ending with `Starting FitNesse on port: 9090`

Next I try to run a test on a test environment, but that fails.

The 1st failure is:
`Could not invoke constructor for SeleniumDriverSetup[0]`

The 2nd failure is:
`The instance scriptTableActor.startDriverFor. does not exist`

This is an HSAC environment.

Comment: I updated the installation guide. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I did not see you question earlier.
It appears I did not update the installation guide when making a change to how the wiki should be started from the IDE. I only updated the project's README.

Anyway the problems lies it the command used in the maven configuration the guide instructed you to make. The Maven command has to be `compile dependency:copy-dependencies exec:exec` and the guide missed the 'dependency:copy-dependencies' part. Using `compile dependency:copy-dependencies exec:exec` should fix your problem.